# How do I get my question deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deletion, closed-questions, self-deletion

I cannot delete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4838274/in-which-bases-is-easy-to-interpret-a-binary-number) because "it has an answer", even when the "answer" does not even attempt to answer the question at all. It only repeats what I wrote in the question, with minimal changes.

Where I wrote that is easy to convert from binary (base m=2) to base 2^n (base m^n), the "answer" just says that is easy to convert from binary (m) to base m^n.

That's a triviality and a platitude. If it were trying to answer, it would talk about converting to bases that are NOT m^n, as I asked.

Comment: (1) Raise a flag asking for deletion.  (2) Wait a few days (particularly during the holidays, when a lot of the moderators are not very active).

Comment: You can also downvote an Answer that doesn't try to resolve your Question.  In this case the Answer's poster claims in a Comment a more comprehensive result than was actually written up, along the lines that nothing can be done easily (to convert from binary) when $b \neq 2$.

Answer (score 4):

If an answer does not answer the question, you can flag it as 'not an answer'.